# How to easily test for guifont in vimrc?

Tags: vim

I have many different machines that I am logging into and none of them have decent fonts in common. So, I would like to be able to have my first preferance for a font but if it does not exist on the machine use another one and so on. Has anyone done this before?

...

So after re-reading the help on guifont it seems that I should be able to have multiple fonts defined seperated by commas. The funny thing is though I have the following line in my .vimrc:

```
set guifont=-dt-interface\ user-medium-r-normal-*-*-100-*-*-m-*-iso8859-1,Liberation\ Mono\ 8
```

And on one machine (gvim 7.1) I do a

```
:set gfn?
guifont=-dt-interface user-medium-r-normal-*-*-100-*-*-m-*-iso8859-1
```

And on another machine (gvim 7.2) I get:

```
:set gfn?
guifont=-dt-interface user-medium-r-normal-*-*-100-*-*-m-*-iso8859-1,Liberation Mono 8
```

I will try to run 7.1 on the incorrect machine and see if it fixes the problem and if so doesn't it seem like a bug in 7.2?

---

### SOLUTION

Here is the code I cam up with to fix the problem. It seems very brittle but it at least allows me to make some progress with my real work for now:

```
" SETTINGS FOR GUI ONLY MODE
: Trying to emulate how it should work but on some machines it will not select the available font
" set guifont=-dt-interface\ user-medium-r-normal-*-*-100-*-*-m-*-iso8859-1,Liberation\ Mono\ 8
let g:MyFontPre = ''
let g:MyFontPost = ''
let g:MyFontSize = '8'
if has("gui_running")
    if ( match(hostname(), 'server5-1..') >= 0 )
      let g:MyFontSize = '10'
      let g:MyFontPre = '-dt-interface\ user-medium-r-normal-*-*-'
      let g:MyFontPost = '0-*-*-m-*-iso8859-1'
    elseif ( match(hostname(), 'server5-3..') >= 0 )
      let g:MyFontPre = 'Liberation\ Mono\ '
      let g:MyFontPost = ''
    else
      " Leave it the default for now
    endif
    execute "set guifont=".g:MyFontPre."".g:MyFontSize."".g:MyFontPost
endif


" FONT SIZE SHORTCUTS
function! ToggleMyFontSize()
  if ( g:MyFontSize == 12 )
    let g:MyFontSize = 8
    execute "set guifont=".g:MyFontPre."".g:MyFontSize."".g:MyFontPost
  elseif ( g:MyFontSize == 8 )
    let g:MyFontSize = 10
    execute "set guifont=".g:MyFontPre."".g:MyFontSize."".g:MyFontPost
  elseif ( g:MyFontSize == 10 )
    let g:MyFontSize = 12
    execute "set guifont=".g:MyFontPre."".g:MyFontSize."".g:MyFontPost
  endif
endfunction
nnoremap  <silent>  <F12> :call ToggleMyFontSize()<CR>
```

Comment: So the other version of vim available on that machine is 7.0 and it gives the same behaviour as I was seeing before with 7.2... Very strange. It must be something with how things where compiled for that particular machine?!?! Does anyone else have any ideas? In the mean time I am working on a solution based on "too much php"'s suggestion.

Comment: I think my IT department should also be using font server xfs so that all the machines have the same fonts available. I have entered a ticket for them to do so. They talk about xfs here: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCD-X-Terminal-6.html

Comment: Also, if you want to use regex, you can do something like this: if hostname() =~ 'server5-1..'

Comment: Best to post the solution as an answer below rather than as an edit to the original question. That way, it can be subject to up/down votes like the rest of the solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a direct solution to your problem, but you could use `hostname()` and a conditional statement to select the font you would like:

```
  if hostname() == 'home-pc'
      set guifont=...
  elseif hostname() == 'work-pc'
      set guifont=...
  else
      set guifont=...
  endif
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that's just....ew. No. The whole point should be to enable easily setting up Vim on a machine you don't know much about or don't have time to configure exactly as you want.

Answer (score 9):

If using commas isn't working for you, how about this to allow graceful font degradation? This trick can be used for other 'set' options as well.

```
silent! set guifont=Font\ One:h8
if &guifont != 'Font One:h8'
    set guifont=Font\ Two:h8
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also place all of your common settings in `.vimrc` and chose the font in a machine-specific `.gvimrc` (if you're a Windows user, use `_vimrc` and `_gvimrc` instead).

I know that this is not a direct answer to your question, but I found it worth the while to point it out. :)

Comment: Yep good idea; I do this via `source ~/local/.vimrc` in my `~/.vimrc`.

Answer (score 0):

Unix only solution, tested on linux. I'm going to guess this will work on OSX but I've never used OSX, sorry.

```
let font = {"name" : "fontNameHere", "size" : "12"}
call system("fc-list -q " . font.name)
if has("unix") && !v:shell_error
    let &guifont=join(values(font))
end
```

Just replace the font name & size in the dictionary with the one you want - i.e,

```
let font = {"name" : "DejaVuSansMono", "size" : "12"}
```